# reCaptchs access to local variables that holds a DOM element from data-callback callback function

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

in my site i have google reCaptcha component which allows me to specify a callback function inside the attribute "data-callback".

this is my html file:

```
<html>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var txtClientResponse = document.getElementById('txtClientResponse');
    var txtServerResponse = document.getElementById('txtServerResponse');

    function successCallback(value) {

        this.txtClientResponse.value = value;
        this.txtServerResponse.innerText.clear();

    }
</script>
<body>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="successCallback" data-error-callback="errorCaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxx" />

    <input ID="txtClientResponse" />
    <input ID="txtServerResponse" />

</body>
```

Everything works great except the fact that i can not access the local variable txtClientResponse, that holds a DOM element, from the callback function "successCallback". to local variables like var test = 1, i can access using this.test.

i tried to pass the "this" using like i am doing on Angular but it didn't work. i need a pure javascript solution - not angular:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="successCallback.bind(this)" data-error-callback="errorCaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxx"/>
```

Comment: Those are global variables, so just refer to them directly (without `this.`).

Comment: Not working for some reason. only functions accessible.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Have you tried putting a `console.log()` in the callback to check?

Comment: I am getting null when doing console.log(this.txtClientResponse). it woks for regular variables but not for variables that holds DOM element like input.

Comment: Have you first created these two elements in the document body?

Comment: Again, get rid of the `this.` prefix. `console.log(txtClientResponse)` in the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use pure JavaScript for long time because i am using Angular, i forgot that the script tag with the javascript code should be at the very bottom of the body tag content or at least to assign the variables with the getElementById inside the document.onreadystatechange event.

The problem was that the lines:

```
var txtClientResponse = document.getElementById('txtClientResponse');
var txtServerResponse = document.getElementById('txtServerResponse');
```

executed before the HTML elements where ready.

Here is the fix for users that may find this question using google

```
<html>    
<body>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="successCallback" data-error-callback="errorCaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxx" />

    <input ID="txtClientResponse" />
    <input ID="txtServerResponse" />

    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var txtClientResponse = document.getElementById('txtClientResponse');
        var txtServerResponse = document.getElementById('txtServerResponse');

        function successCallback(value) {

            this.txtClientResponse.value = value;
            this.txtServerResponse.innerText.clear();

        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```